# How to implement bookmark functionality and divide chapters into multiple pages of epub file?

Tags: android

I have unzip and parse the epub file and render it in Webview.  Now I want to know how can I implement bookmark functionality , search text and most important divide chapters into multiple pages. If any one have any idea related this then please share with me.

Comment: I am also having same issue.If you find the solution please share it.